# Can you add CLI tools to a Cloud Foundry app?

Tags: cloud-foundry

Terribly sorry if this is an obvious question. But I have a webapp that relies on a CLI tool to get it to work. I was wondering if there was a way I could specify this without using a custom buildpack. And how to go about doing this if possible

Any help on this would be great, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can you add CLI tools to a Cloud Foundry app?

It's not possible to directly install things with `apt` or `apt-get`. Your app runs as an unprivileged user and is unable to run those tools to install things.

This leaves you with a couple options:

1. Get the binary and bundle it with your app. Some people (no judgement from me though) would say that your app is responsible for bringing everything it needs to run anyway, so you should be doing this already.

   > Twelve-factor apps also do not rely on the implicit existence of any system tools. Examples include shelling out to ImageMagick or curl. [1]

   This path works well for dependencies that are small or self contained, like statically built Go apps. If your app need shared libraries or other resources to function, you need to bundle those with your app too. It's also not great if the size of what you bundle is large. Everything you bundle will be pushed up with the app, so it can slow down your pushes. You are also responsible for tracking updates and making sure that you have the latest, bug free & security patched binaries & libraries.

   The general steps for doing this are:

   1. Create a folder like `binaries/` under the root of your app, with subfolders of `bin/` and `lib/`.
   2. Place all your binaries under `binaries/bin` and any shared libraries they require under `binaries/lib`.
   3. Add a `.profile` file at the root of your app. This will be sourced prior to your app starting so it will put any binaries you bundle on the path and add libraries to the search path.

      In `.profile` put the following:

      ```
      export PATH=$HOME/binaries/bin:$PATH
      export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/binaries/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
      ```

   That should be it. Just push your app with all the new files.
2. Another easier option, is to use the Apt buildpack [2]. This buildpack can install required dependencies using `apt`. You just need to add an `apt.yml` file to the root of your app & run your app with multi-buildpacks (apt buildpack first, then your normal buildpack).

   The main benefit of doing this is that you don't have to manage the dependencies. The apt buildpack will automatically install them from the repo you tell it to use, so it'll pick up new versions from there as well. This is good if what you need to install has a lot of dependencies, particularly sensitive dependencies (like openssl) or dependencies that get updated/patched often like other language runtimes (Python, Perl, Ruby, etc...).

   Other benefits. It's easier because the buildpack takes care of adjusting PATH & LD_LIBRARY_PATH. It also makes the app size smaller so pushes are faster.

   The downsides of this option are that the apt-buildpack is not an official buildpack (it's community maintained). It also works best when you have Internet access, so it can download binaries from the Internet, although you can work around this by using an internal repo.

---

There's a couple other options as well, but I wouldn't recommend them unless both options above are definitely not going to work for you.

1. Use Docker. You can set up your own Docker container with all the dependencies you need, plus your app code and `cf push` the Docker image to CF. The downside of this is that your lose the advantages of using buildpacks, so you're back to building and managing Docker images and all the required dependencies of your app all on your own.
2. You could create your own custom buildpack and supply the dependencies that way. I don't see any reason you'd want to do this though. It's a decent bit of work and in the end, you'd have something that's just more brittle and less flexible than Apt Buildpack.
3. It's technically possible to ship your own rootfs, but you really really shouldn't (I'm just including this to be thorough). This is the base file system that's used by all apps on CF. Doing this has a lot of drawbacks though, chiefly being that it's difficult. It also applies to all apps on the foundation, can bloat the size of the rootfs, and makes a larger attack surface for anything using the rootfs (i.e. all apps).

Hope that helps!

- [1] https://12factor.net/dependencies
- [2] https://github.com/cloudfoundry/apt-buildpack

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! Hopefully this helps the next person with the same question:)